# pygame.FULLSCREEN returns blank screen instead of proper display

Tags: python, pygame

I am following a tutorial to understand pygame. In this game i just set background color, and draw a image of ship and also handle events to manage position of ship (image). My code works properly in static screen size but gives blank screen when i try to open in full screen mode.  Here is the properly working code for AlienInvasion class

```
class AlienInvasion:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((self.settings.width, self.settings.height))
        # width and height are static value 1366 and 768

        pg.display.set_caption('Pygame')
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.x = float(self.ship.rect.x)

        self.move_right = False
        self.move_left = False

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.update()
            self._update_screen()

    # Function to manage events
    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if(event.type == pg.QUIT):
                sys.exit()
            elif(event.type == pg.KEYDOWN):
                self._check_keydown_events(event)

            elif(event.type == pg.KEYUP):
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    # manage key down events
    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        if(event.key == pg.K_RIGHT):
            self.move_right = True
        elif(event.key == pg.K_LEFT):
            self.move_left = True
        elif(event.key == pg.K_q):
            sys.exit()
    # manage key up enevts

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        if(event.key == pg.K_RIGHT):
            self.move_right = False
        elif(event.key == pg.K_LEFT):
            self.move_left = False

    # Update position of image object
    def update(self):
        if(self.move_right and self.ship.rect.right < self.ship.screen_rect.right):
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        elif(self.move_left and self.ship.rect.left > 0):
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed

        self.ship.rect.x = self.x

    # Actual Function that set background and display image object
    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        pg.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Code for Settings class

```
class Settings:
def __init__(self):
    self.width = 1366
    self.height = 768
    self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
    self.ship_speed = 1.5
```

Code for Ship class

```
class Ship:
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

def blitme(self):
    a = self.screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect[0], self.rect[1] - 70))
```

finally ship.bmp
[image]

Here is the updated code of AlienInvasion.**init** function to open in full screen mode

```
def __init__(self):
    pg.init()
    self.settings = Settings()
    # Updated lines start
    self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((0, 0), pg.FULLSCREEN)
    self.settings.width = self.screen.get_rect().width
    self.settings.height = self.screen.get_rect().height
    # End Update Lines
    pg.display.set_caption('Pygame')
    self.ship = Ship(self)
    self.x = float(self.ship.rect.x)

    self.move_right = False
    self.move_left = False
```

Now it shows a blank black screen. I cant understand why

Comment: Please add `Settings` and `Ship` classed definition

Comment: Ok updating my question

Comment: And also please share `images/ship.bmp` file

Comment: Done. ship.bmp is also added

Comment: Checked and it works fine for me with Full Screen option

Comment: I see a black screen in fullscreen, and the correct white background and ship image when windowed.

Comment: Ok I noticed that on my main screen with 2k resolution, the screen is black, but on my laptop screen with FullHD resolution, the image is shown correctly. No idea why however. Edit: if I use `pg.display.set_mode((2560, 1440))` the window is created correctly, but with the top bar (as it is a window).

Comment: @MudasirHabib please share your operating system, pygame version, how you installed pygame, and python version.

Comment: i am working on ubuntu 20.04, pygame 2.0.1, python 3.8.5 I dont remember how i was installed pygame but mostly i install python libraries by "python3 -m pip install pygame"